# htaccess -> Redirect category without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a category without trailing slash ecommerce.com/category1 to ecommerce.com/category1/

But, only categories. Products ending with .html should stay with html.

I've tried a combination but it doesnt work.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I have also this rules in htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Just to clarify, it's a Prestashop

thanks

Comment: So basically, can we say: add a trailing slash, except for files?

Comment: The rule you've posted should already do as you require. What do you mean exactly by "doesnt work"? Are you getting an error? Undesirable redirect? Nothing? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file? Where have you placed this rule exactly? Are "categories" always the first path segment? What does a full "product URL" look like? Is the "product" URL that ends with `.html` a physical file?

Comment: "I have also this rules in htaccess" - But _where_? What order do you have these rules? And what else do you have? Presumably you have a `RewriteEngine` directive?